# Formatting issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, formatting, specific-answer

What's going on with Code Reviewer formatting engine?  I've had a few issues with [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/56824/49106).

Please <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for

> Now, if we already caught the exception in the inner try-block by adding a catch block

You will see that block is messed up. I can't figure out what's causing the problem. I can fix it with new line breaks before and after that block, but it won't accept my edit as it says it needs at least 6 characters to change.

Comment: Nice answer BTW ;)

Comment: Haha yeah superb answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited your post.

Honestly, I have no idea what was wrong with it. I just selected the code block, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>'d twice (I actually clicked the <kbd>{ }</kbd> button in the editing toolbar twice), and that fixed it.

Comment: Thanks man, so maybe just spacing issues not bug huh?

Comment: For some reason, that line contained the character U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE (commonly written as `&nbsp;`) which is why it wasn't showing correctly.